# Sudo apt-get install git problem

Tags: apt, 14.10, git

Hi Im kinda new to Ubuntu. That said, I can usually run this on a clean install of ubunty 14.10

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

And then git should be installed

But what I get is this

```
me@server1:~$ sudo apt-get install git
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.4.5-.) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-client-5.5 : Breaks: mariadb-server-5.5 (< 5.5.44-1ubuntu0.14.10.1) but 5.5.39-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
me@server1:~$ git
The program 'git' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install git
me@server1:~$
```

it looks like `apt-get` does not install the dependencies automatically, and the `git` command just returs `git is currently not installed`. Running `sudo apt-get -f install` does not change anything

What am I doing wrong here? (Note: I dont want mariadb installed)

EDIT:
After running `sudo apt-get purge mariadb-client-5.5`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.39-2) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-server-5.5 : Depends: mariadb-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.39-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: I also tried `sudo apt-get install git-core` it does not work either. It just tells me that git-core depends on git

Comment: try to install it via Synaptic, if you have it installed, it will probably make no difference. Or if  `git` is from external PPA, do: `sudo apt-get update`  
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install -f` and after that try to install git

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. I cant install synaptic.. I seem to run into the same problem.. it tells me that tere are missing dependencies

Comment: look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories because you have probably messed up your source list somehow

Comment: I dot have a gui that I can use, and now I deleted my source list and cant get it back

Comment: here you can generate source list http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: Could you please add to your question the output of `sudo apt-get purge mariadb-client-5.5` ?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming because, your apt-get dependency tree has reached an inconstant state, due to the installation of **mariadb-client** package which is of newer/older version than as as expected by **mariadb-server**.

Try uninstalling mariadb-client by

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mariadb-client-5.5
```

Then try to correct your dependency tree by

```
 $ sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then try installing git.

Comment: I just tried this, when I run the first command I get the same dependency errors mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-5.5 and mariadb-server-5.5 : Depends: mariadb-client-5.5 

After running the next command and trying to install git I get the samme response as before

Comment: If there is "no data loss involved", try uninstalling the server package. by $sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server-5.5, and then try the $sudo apt-get -f install